# I am getting rounded number INSERTS into MySQL with two decimal spots using ORM in CF

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion

I have my column datatype set to DECIMAL(10,2) and have dumped my query to verify the variable includes values past the decimal points, but the dump following the insert shows my "itemPrice" to be a rounded whole number with two zeros after the decimal point. However if I  the variable used to set "itemPrice" after the script, I get the right numbers formatted properly - so am not sure what my mistake is.  The code is below.  Excuse the rough nature of this code - I am just getting back into CF after 10 years without coding...

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#downloadDir#import.xls" query="qxldata" excludeheaderrow="yes" columnnames="PartNumber,Name,Price,Category,IsActive,Location,Description,remarks,SubLocation">


<cfloop query="qxldata" startrow="3" endrow="4">

<cfquery name="noDup">
    SELECT * FROM Items
    WHERE itemPN = #qxldata.PartNumber#
</cfquery>
    <cfif noDup.RecordCount EQ 0>


    <cfscript>
        //Insert a new item
        item = new items();
        item.setitemPN(PartNumber);
        item.setitemName(Name);
        item.setitemCategory(Category);
        item.setitemDescription(Description);
        item.setitemBarcodeName("bc"&PartNumber&".jpg");
        item.setitemImageName(PartNumber&".jpg");
        //item.setitemReorderPoint(#listgetAt('#i#',7, ',')#);
        //item.setitemReorderQuantity(#listgetAt('#i#',8, ',')#);
        item.setitemLocation(Location);
        item.setitemSubLocation(SubLocation);
        //item.setitemLength(#listgetAt('#i#',11, ',')#);
        //item.setitemWidth(#listgetAt('#i#',12, ',')#);
        //item.setitemHeight(#listgetAt('#i#',13, ',')#);
        item.setitemRemarks(remarks);
        item.setitemIsActive(IsActive);
        item.setitemVendorID("1");
        IF(Price NEQ ''){
        item.setitemPrice(Price);
        }
        EntitySave(item);
    </cfscript>
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput>
        #Price#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Here is my CFC:

```
component persistent="true" table="items" {

    property name="itemID" fieldtype="id" generator="increment";
    property itemPN;
    property itemName;
    property itemCategory;
    property itemDescription;
    property itemBarcodeName;
    property itemImageName;
    property itemReorderPoint;
    property itemReorderQuantity;
    property itemLocation;
    property itemSubLocation;
    property itemLength;
    property itemWidth;
    property itemHeight;
    property itemRemarks;
    property itemIsActive;
    property itemVendorID;
    property itemPrice;
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Please edit your question as follows.  First, take away all that barcode stuff.  It's irrelevent.  Next, add the code for the setItemPrice() method.

Comment: What query did you dump? I suspect that the issue is that you are not using any of the attributes of the property to define the property, such as `type` or `ormtype`. My guess is that because these are not defined, Hibernate treats all numbers as integers. Try adding `ormtype="double"` to the _itemPrice_ property

Comment: Dan - unless he overrode the `setItemPrice()` method, there will be no code to show. With ORM, you get implicit accessors.

Comment: Thank you for the input!  Scott, you were correct - I needed to add an ormtype to itemPrice.  When I dove into ORM, I thought I read somewhere that CF would determine the DB Column attributes and act accordingly.  I will start using types/ormtypes moving forward.

Comment: by default ORM uses the property definition but I you can tell it to use the DB for mapping by adding `useDBForMapping = true` in your ORM config. Docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSED380324-6CBE-47cb-9E5E-26B66ACA9E81.html

Comment: @ScottStroz (or toddarc) - Sounds like you solved the problem. One of you should post an official "answer" to close out the thread.